# Listview with dynamic Strings coded in c# (Xamarin Mono)

Tags: c#, android, list, listview, xamarin

I'm struggling a bit with the conversion of my Windows Forms C# Project to Android.
Strictly speaking the populating of a `ListView` is causing me problems.

In the Windows project its a a piece of cake with:

```
foreach(...){
...
listBox1.Items.Add(res[3] + " | " + res[0] + " | " + lang);
...
}
```

(res is a List of Strings that get filled by a regex)

But in Android its not that easy I suppose. 
I created a `ListView` in the Main Layout

```
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Then I create a ListView in the Activity with

```
ListView list1;
list1 = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);
```

Last step, the Adapter, is where things start to get tricky.
If I understand correct it is not possible to use the standard `ArrayAdapter` in my case. Because I don't have a full and finished Array that feds the Adapter.

My attempt:

```
string temp = (res[3] + " | " + res[0] + " | " + lang);
list1.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, temp);
```

So how do I deal properly with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding items to the list box one by one. The same using an adapter

```
var list = new List<string>();

foreach(...){
...
//listBox1.Items.Add(res[3] + " | " + res[0] + " | " + lang);
list.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}", res[3], res[0], lang));
...
}

list1.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, 
   Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, 
   list.ToArray());
```

or alternatively:

```
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, 
   Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);

// uncomment if you want live update
// list1.Adapter = adapter;

foreach(...){
    adapter.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2}", res[3], res[0], lang));
    // uncomment if you want live update
    // adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}

// comment out if you want live update
list1.Adapter = adapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using an array for one item, but the way to handle this is to do:

```
list1.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, 
   Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, 
   new string[] { temp });
```

Take the single value, and convert it to an array for the purpose of the list.  As with anything, since you supply the data, you can always convert it to the format the list needs.